# How does Matzah contribute to simchas yom tov

Tags: halacha-theory, yom-tov, matzah, simchah-joy-happiness

I always understood the concept/reason to sometimes be lenient, known as מניעת שמחת יום טוב, a lack or decrease in the joy of Yom Tov, to be referring to cases where a significant portion of the meal will be compromised. For example, a large, tasty roast beef, or a large chunk of the meal. If these things would be forbidden, his *simchas yom tov* will be decreased, so we are sometimes lenient and permit the issue.

Perhaps my attitude is wrong, but I would be surprised to apply this concept to matzah. Let's say there's a halachic problem with the matzah, I never would have thought to apply the concept of מניעת שמחת יום טוב to permit it, or even bother mentioning it doesn't apply for some other reason. If so, I was surprised by the following comment of the Noda B'Yehudah (Tinyana, Orach Chaim 80), brought by the Shaarei Teshuva to Shulchan Aruch OC 461:6 and Mishnah Berurah ad. loc. 15:

> אבל אם גם בקרימה של המצה יש לו ספק אם זה מיחשב קרימה או לא, הא ודאי שזה ספק כרת הוא וחוששין שמא נתחמצה, **ואין אנו משגיחין לא בהפסד מרובה ולא במניעת שמחת יום טוב ואוסרין אותה**

I understand he's *not* applying this principle in this case, but the fact that he even had to mention it means one could have thought it could apply. He didn't mention for example *bittul beshishim*, as that's obviously not relevant here.

So what am I missing? Is it enough that he won't be able to have a *halachic seudah* that I would call this a diminishment of Yom Tov joy? Or that he won't be able to fulfill the *mitzvah* of eating *matzah*? As I said, I thought this principle was a physical pleasure for a spiritual purpose, which I thought is the way to fulfill *simchas yom tov*.

Comment: What type of enjoyable meal is not based on bread?

Comment: @JoelK that may be the context but not the enjoyable part. At least not dry, thin, burnt matzah for some people. (Personally I enjoy it)

Comment: Maybe in Noda Bihuda's time they were still baking normal matzah? Rama only says that matzah shouldn't be thicker than a tefach

Comment: @JoelK could be but in the Mishnah Berurah who brings him Ashkenazim only had thin matzos. Also I thought the SA says that and the Rema says to make thin (460:4-5).

Comment: you could be right. i haven't looked at the sugya for a while

Comment: Those who dont eat gebrokts (todays fashion) are also accused of that.

Comment: @robev thin doesn't mean hard

Comment: Nowadays we're used to the idea that meals need not have bread, but that wasn't always the case.

Comment: @DoubleAA that's what I was wondering. It's not called Simcha without a meal, and a meal isn't a meal without bread?

Comment: In halacha, bread is viewed as main course of meal. Same with matzah come Pesach time.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.188.8.1

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess that's a good answer. Feel free to post.